How do I report an error from AWS Lambda to my PHP app?
I have a PHP application that transfers images to AWS S3 Buckets. It uploads images to a temporary bucket, and a Lambda function triggers the creation of thumbnails in various dimensions, which are then sent to the main bucket. Here's the code for the Lambda function:
import boto3
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import os
import io

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
output_bucket = "laravo-cloud"

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 500000000  # Allows images up to 500 million pixels

WEBHOOK_URL = "https://your-webhook-url.com"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
    original_image_key = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]

    # Check if the image path matches "xxxx/product_images/original/"
    if "product_images/original/" not in original_image_key:
        print(
            f"Skipping file {original_image_key} as it does not match the required path."
        )
        return

    # Parse the image path
    parts = original_image_key.split("/")
    org_id = parts[0]
    image_name = parts[-1]
    image_extension = image_name.split(".")[-1]

    # Download the original image from S3
    original_image_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=original_image_key)
    original_image = Image.open(original_image_obj["Body"])

    # Define sizes for 1:1 and 5:8 thumbnails
    sizes_1x1 = [(size, size) for size in range(100, 901, 50)]
    sizes_5x8 = [(size, int(size * 8 / 5)) for size in range(100, 901, 50)]

    # Reduce the image size initially to optimize memory usage
    original_image.thumbnail((1000, 1000), Image.LANCZOS)

    # Copy the original image to the output bucket
    s3.copy_object(
        Bucket=output_bucket,
        CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': original_image_key},
        Key=f"{org_id}/product_images/original/{image_name}",
        ACL='public-read'
    )

    # Generate 1:1 thumbnails
    for size in sizes_1x1:
        generate_thumbnail_and_upload(
            original_image,
            size,
            org_id,
            "1x1",
            bucket_name,
            image_name,
            image_extension,
        )

    # Generate 5:8 thumbnails
    for size in sizes_5x8:
        generate_thumbnail_and_upload(
            original_image,
            size,
            org_id,
            "5x8",
            bucket_name,
            image_name,
            image_extension,
        )

    # Remove the original image from S3
    s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=original_image_key)


# Generate a thumbnail and upload it to S3
def generate_thumbnail_and_upload(
    original_image,
    target_size,
    org_id,
    ratio_folder,
    bucket_name,
    image_name,
    image_extension,
):
    # Calculate the aspect ratio
    aspect_ratio = original_image.width / original_image.height
    target_aspect = target_size[0] / target_size[1]

    if aspect_ratio > target_aspect:
        # Fit to width
        new_width = target_size[0]
        new_height = int(new_width / aspect_ratio)
    else:
        # Fit to height
        new_height = target_size[1]
        new_width = int(new_height * aspect_ratio)

    # Resize the image
    img_resized = original_image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.LANCZOS)

    # Create a new blank image with white background
    thumb_image = Image.new("RGB", target_size, (255, 255, 255))

    # Paste the resized image onto the center of the new image
    paste_x = (target_size[0] - new_width) // 2
    paste_y = (target_size[1] - new_height) // 2
    thumb_image.paste(img_resized, (paste_x, paste_y))

    # Save the thumbnail to a bytes buffer
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    save_format = "JPEG" if image_extension == "jpg" else image_extension.upper()
    thumb_image.save(buffer, format=save_format)
    buffer.seek(0)

    # Define the thumbnail path
    size_folder = str(target_size[0])  # using width as the size folder name
    thumb_image_key = (
        f"{org_id}/product_images/{ratio_folder}/{size_folder}/{image_name}"
    )

    # Upload the thumbnail back to S3
    s3.put_object(
        Bucket=output_bucket,
        Key=thumb_image_key,
        Body=buffer,
        ContentType=f"image/{image_extension.lower()}",
        ACL='public-read'
    )

This function may fail before execution due to throttling from too many concurrent requests or may be interrupted during processing. I want to report these issues to my PHP app by sending a request that includes the issue name, organization ID, and either the image name or the S3 bucket link containing the organization ID and image name. How can I achieve this?
I attempted to set up an AWS CloudWatch alert to trigger an SNS notification, which would invoke another Lambda function to send a POST request to my app, but it didn't provide relevant or usable information.

What does this mean?  My sense is this approach should work, if you do it correctly: "I attempted to set up an AWS CloudWatch alert to trigger an SNS notification, which would invoke another Lambda function to send a POST request to my app, but it didn't provide relevant or usable information."  More details might help.

Thank you for your response. To clarify: I upload images to a temporary S3 bucket at the path {organization_id/images/{product_id}.extension. Once uploaded, a Lambda function transfers the image to the main bucket with modifications. I want to extract the organization_id and product_id to send to the system in case of failure.

There are a lot of missing details here.  It's going to be hard for someone to answer this question in a helpful way unless you provide clear documentation about each step (including relevant minimal code) and what the exact workflow is.  Please add those things to your question (not in the comments.)
